# Use pretérito imperfecto or pretérito indefinido?

Tags: gramática, verbos, pretérito-imperfecto, pretérito-perfecto

I have the following sentence :

> Los invitados (llamar) ______ a la puerta y les (abrir) _____ una joven (ser) _____ una muchacha.

I think that it should be the following :

> Los invitados (llamar) **llamaban** a la puerta y les (abrir) **abrio** una joven (ser) **era** una muchacha.

Yet, I'm not sure since (abrir) aka opening the door, is an action that terminated in the past she open the door the action was finished when the door was open if I use **abria** doesn't it mean that the action is still taking place? like she is just opening the door? I'm a bit confused.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you say

> Los invitados llamaban a la puerta y les abrió una joven, era una muchacha.

it sounds like the door was opened *while* the guests were knocking at the door. You get the same meaning with

> Los invitados llamaban a la puerta cuando les abrió una joven.
>   Los invitados estaban llamando a la puerta cuando les abrió una joven.

If the door was opened *after* the knocking, you must use *llamaron*:

> Los invitados llamaron a la puerta y les abrió una joven. Era una muchacha.

Note that you must you a comma or period before the *era*. About your question, yes, you must use *abrió* as the action was executed once and has already finished. If you use *abría* it sounds as an action that was executed regularly, as in the following example:

> Siempre que llamaban a la puerta les abría la misma muchacha.

Answer (score 1):

**Abrió** is the correct one, since the action has already happened and finished.

Also the you have to use a coma after era:

Los invitados (llamar) **llamaban** a la puerta y les (abrir) **abrió** una joven (ser)**,** **era** una muchacha.

Comment: Qué tal si usásemos "llamaron"? Habría alguna diferencia? Date cuenta de que la pregunta busca comparar dos tiempos verbales. Esta respuesta mejoraría mucho si explicases porqué prefieres un tiempo verbal en lugar a otro.

Comment: @Diego Si usas `llamaban` implica que mientras se estaba realizando la acción de llamar a la puerta la joven la abrió y si usas `llamaron` implica que primeron realizaron la acción de llamar y después la joven abrió. En este ejemplo ambas serían correctas ya que no hay contexto que nos ayude a elegir una de las dos opciones. EDIT: Acabo de ver que justo lo que te acabo de decir lo ha explicado Carlos más arriba, él lo explica mejor jeje.